# how do I get a fade in animation for <li> using React or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

How do I use react or CSS to fade in li tags when they are initially hidden?  I have the code so the ul is shown and the li comes in when the mouse is hovered over it.  However, how do I get the li to animate in like in JQuery?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SideBar extends Component {
    state = {
        activeItem: ''
    };
    mouseOver = () => {
        console.log('in');
        this.setState({activeItem: 'collapsed' });
    };
    mouseOut = () => {
        console.log('out');
        this.setState({activeItem: '' });
    };  

    render() {
        const { activeItem, hovering } = this.state;

        return(
    <header className="main-header">
        <div className="main-header-frame">
            <div className="header-wrapper">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a onMouseLeave={this.mouseOut} onMouseOver={this.mouseOver} href='/test'>Test1</a>
                            <ul className={activeItem === "collapsed" ? 'display' : 'disappear'}>
                                <li>t1</li>
                                <li>t2</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
            )
    }
};

export default SideBar;
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
.disappear {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
    transition: all 1.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.6s ease-in-out;  
    transition-delay: .4s;  
}
```

Comment: did you try using ReactCSSTransitionGroup ? checkout https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G I'm currently reading it now.

Comment: But how do I get to fade in the li element?

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of missing stuff in your CSS Code,

```
.disappear {
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
    transition: all 1.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.6s ease-in-out;  
    transition-delay: .4s;  
}
```

You're trying to hide/show using display:none, display is not an "animatable" property. Instead you can use opacity. Read more about properties that you can animate here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties

Additionally, the transition and transition-delay needs to be applied on the li element before changing opacity property.

A better approach would be:

```
li {
  transition: all 1.6s ease-in-out; //Add transition on the element regardless of display status
}
.disappear { 
  opacity: 0; // Change opacity to 0 when it hides
}
```

Now, if an element has opacity:0, it will disappear from screen, but you want it to collapse, instead you also need to change the height to 0 to make the element actually disappear. Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/khodor/pen/yQYqpO)

Animating height is not the best option, since changing the height causes the browser to recalculate positions and the animation will appear jittery. Instead you need to animate transform and opacity. Read more about performant animation [here](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108)